# LM2776 is it normal to have the oscillations in "bursts"

Tags: inverter, oscillation, charge-pump

Is it normal LM2776 to oscillate in "bursts":

[image]
[image]

The frequency of the oscillation is OK, but they come in the 8 oscillation bursts every ~9us.

Is it normal? The board design and the schematic is exactly the same as in the DS.

The LM2776 is giving me the correct negative voltage and I draw about 50mA from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. See section 7.3.2 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2776.pdf).

Comment: I have missed this paragraph. Thank you. I will accept the answer in three minutes (have to wait 6 minutes before the system allows it)